# SMTPConnectError (421, b'Server busy, too many connections')SMTPConnectError (421, b'Server busy, too many connections')

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I have checked every single solution on other questions but they are of zero help,using bulk email services also require having a domain name already meanwhile my django website is still in development but i also want to send actual mails not mail on django console.I have allowed access to less secure apps,used app password and re capcha all to no avail,i even changed my email host to yahoo mail still the same thing,the fact that email verification is a core part of authentication and there's little to no support or help is very annoying,already looked through all youtube videos it worked for them but non worked for me
my settings file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

the error mesage:

```
SMTPConnectError (421, b'Server busy, too many connections')
```

Comment: How many emails you are trying to send, do you know that Gmail sets a rate limit of 20 outgoing emails per hour?

Comment: i'm only trying to send one mail at a time,just an email confirmation mail to a user trying to register

Comment: Hello @Precious112 were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @Joel unfortunately no I haven't

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue yesterday with Django using SendGrid. What fixed it for me was setting:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.sendgrid.net"

EMAIL_HOST_USER = "username"

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"

EMAIL_PORT = 465

EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```